# Is Product Scanner better than Barcode Scanner?

Tags: computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, barcode, barcode-scanner, image-scanner

For example, scanning the wine to tell you its name by Vivino.
But, seriously, scanning its barcode is faster and easier with high accuracy. Why do they design to use AI to scan the product by computer vision (object identification)? Is it necessary, mate?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question that is appropriate for this site.
Your question is likely to be a statement of opinion.

The answer is, not which is better, but the issue of segregation.
The product scanner does not replace the barcode scanner. At least soon.

For example, there are products that do not have source marking and are difficult to apply in-store marking.
In order to save labor, reduce time, standardize, and mechanize these products, product scanners that use AI will be good parts.

In addition, even for products that already have barcodes, it is possible to acquire the information of the target actual product and display it additionally.

At first, every product has a part that seems useless and exaggerated.
However, according to market evaluations, some of them will disappear and some will be sophisticated and essential.

That's always happening and your question seems to be one of them.